# In SpriteKit, how to make a cropped (with transparent segments) image of my hero sprite?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, transparency, crop, transparent

I am using SpriteKit, and only beginning how to develop for iOS. How can I make some parts of the image of my game hero transparent so it is displayed properly in the scene? I don't want it displayed inside a rectangle which has white parts in its corners, since - as expected - my hero is not in the shape of a rectangle, so I have a surplus. I know it has something to deal with transparency, or maybe cropping? I tried using irfanview in all ways that I could think of and no use, the image is always displayed as a rectangle and looks ugly on the scene. I used irfanview before to make things transparent in Flash, but in SpriteKit apparently this doesn't work that well.

Comment: You should always update your question with what you have tried so far to show an effort in solving the issue. Doing that will make your question more understandable and you are not risking of being downvoted. You can read help section to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And about your question itself. If you ask how to make an image with transparent parts, it's easy, use your favourite image editor, make your hero, and save it in .png to preserve transparency. If that is not what you are trying to do, please refine your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming, it's about how to edit images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just solved it by using Preview on Mac - use the magic wand tool in the Preview app on mac to remove the white color - click and drag to make the segments that you wish to be deleted (transparent). After the selection has been done, click delete and then save the image and voila! When you import it into XCode for a sprite, the sprite now looks good and just as I wanted, the white parts are transparent so background can be seen in those places.

Comment: Seriously?  This question is about how to create sprite images with alpha?